# How to apply human_time to get_the_modified_time?

Tags: wordpress

I am using this variable and it works correctly:

```
echo '<i class="fa fa-clock"></i> ' . str_replace('', '', human_time_diff( get_the_time('G'), current_time('timestamp') ) . '');
```

But now I need to make it work by changing get_the_time to get_the_modified_time and it doesn't work, it shows me a result from 50 years ago

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed.

I add it in this answer in case someone needs it:

```
<?php 

$lastmodified = get_the_modified_time('U');
$posted = get_the_time('U');

  if ($lastmodified > $posted) {
     echo "Posted: " . human_time_diff($lastmodified,current_time('U')) . "";   
     } else {
     echo 'Edited: ' . str_replace('', '', human_time_diff( get_the_time('G'), current_time('timestamp') ) . '');
     } 

?>
```